# Images and links not "aligned"

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I'm having an odd issue with an image serving as a link, in which the "clickable" area is not aligned with the image itself.  Here are some images to give an idea what I mean:

[nonclickable http://www.lmnt5.com/01nonclickable.jpg](http://www.lmnt5.com/01nonclickable.jpg)   [clickable http://www.lmnt5.com/02clickable.jpg](http://www.lmnt5.com/02clickable.jpg)

In the phone icon on the left, the position of the cursor should make the link active, but it's not.  Only when I hover the cursor over the top of the icon (as well as in the area immediately above it) does the link become active (as in the photo on the right).

So before I get into de-bugging (or posting code), I was wondering if anyone knows off the top of their head what might be causing this.  (In case it makes any difference, there are three icons inline [phone, Facebook, Twitter]).

[EDIT: per request for code] Here is the relevant html:

```
<div id="socialButtonsWrap">
<div id="socialButtons" class="socialButtons">
<a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="assets/images/badgeFacebook.png" alt="Connect on Facebook"></a>
<a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="assets/images/badgeTwitter.png" alt="Connect on Twitter"></a>
<a href="tel:123456789"><img src="assets/images/badgePhone.png" alt="Click to call"></a>
</div>
</div><!-- close socialButtonsWrap -->
```

And css:

```
#socialButtons {
float: right;
width: 20%;
}

.socialButtons img {
position: relative;
float: right;
padding: 30px 0 0 15px;
max-width: 42px;
max-height: 42px;
}
```

The #socialButtonsWrap only comes into play responsively and the problem was there before I added that div.

Comment: Please add your html in the question.

Comment: have you provided the image dimension in the image tag likewise below `<img src="imagepath" width="Xpx" height="Ypx">`?

Comment: Just tried adding in width/height to the html, but that doesn't fix it.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: the float in the `img` is probably the guilty one. Remove it to test.

Comment: @jackJoe Tried that now -- problem remains...

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a z-index: 999 to the .socialButtons img class and it worked.